# JS: Updating a variable within an if statement and then using that variable in the statements condition?

Tags: javascript

This has got me stumped. I'm creating a simple function that generates a random number between 1 and 6 when an element is clicked (a dice roll).

I want to use an if statement to do something if the number rolled is *not* a 1 or if the previous number rolled is *not* a 6, eg:

`if(dice !== 1 || lastRoll !== 6) { //Do something`

However, I cannot seem to get the OR condition working here. Both `dice !== 1` and `lastRoll !== 6` work fine independantly, but when combined with the OR condition in one if statement neither work.

My complete function is as such:

```
var lastRoll = 0;

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;        
    console.log('current ' + dice + ' last ' + lastRoll); //<-- This displays expected results

   if(dice !== 1 || lastRoll !== 6) {
     lastRoll = dice;
     console.log('success');
   }
   else {
     lastRoll = 0;
     console.log('fail');
   }
}
```

Would anyone know why the OR condition doesn't work?

UPDATE:

To test I did this:

```
var hardCoded = 6;
if(dice !== 1 || hardCoded !== 6) {
```

So I expect the condition to always fail. But it doesn't. It still doesn't like the if statement.

Comment: Are you sure you want OR here? Because with `if(dice !== 1 || lastRoll !== 6)` condition it logs success every time since it 6 passes with the 1st condition and 1 passes with the second condition. I think you need AND here.`if(dice !== 1 && lastRoll !== 6)`

Comment: @Kavindra but I don't want both conditions to be true. I want the condition to fail if they roll a 1 regardless of what the lastRoll is and vice-versa. Basically, if either condition is met it should fail, regardless of what the other variable holds.

Comment: Think about your example again. Even if your `hardcoded` is 6, if the `dice` is not 1, it doesn't even check for the second condition since it is an OR and the first condition passes. It checks the `hardcoded` value only if the `dice` value is 1. You can't expect it to be failed.

Comment: Give some example values as of which scenarios should be passed and which scenarios should be failed to understand your requirement properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, I guess want you want is `if(dice !== 1 && lastRoll !== 6)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I don't think it's what I need. This will fail if `dice = 1 ` and `lastRoll = 6` simultaneously. Where as I want it to fail if `dice = 1` OR if `lastRoll = 6` OR `if dice = 1 and lastRoll = 6`

Comment: @MeltingDog The behavior you described you want is exactly what this does with `&&'`. This answer is logically equivalent to `! ( dice == 1 || lastRoll == 6 )`. That's DeMorgan's rule.

Answer (score 0):

Make your if statement like below and check,
First you need to do something if the roll is not 1:

```
var lastRoll = 0;

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;        
  console.log('current ' + dice + ' last ' + lastRoll); //<-- This displays expected results

  if(dice !== 1) {
    //dice can be 2,3,4,5,6
    console.log('success');
  }
  else {
    console.log('fail');
  }
  lastRoll = dice;
}
```

Then you need the last roll not to be 6:

```
var lastRoll = 0;

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;        
  console.log('current ' + dice + ' last ' + lastRoll); //<-- This displays expected results

  if(dice !== 1) {
    //dice can be 2,3,4,5,6 and lastRoll can be 1,2,3,4,5,6
    if(lastRoll !== 6) {
      //dice can be 2,3,4,5,6 and lastRoll can be 1,2,3,4,5
      console.log('success');
    } else {
      // dice can be 2,3,4,5,6 lastRoll = 6
      console.log('fail');
    }
  }
  else {
    // dice can be 1 lastRoll can be 1,2,3,4,5,6
    console.log('fail');
  }
  lastRoll = dice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@MeltingDog - your code looks fine to me. It's just a very rare occurrence. If you pause the script with debugger here:

```
        var lastRoll = 0;
        var condition;

        document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {

            var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;        
            console.log('current ' + dice + ' last ' + lastRoll); //<-- This displays expected results

            debugger;
            condition = (dice !== 1 || lastRoll !== 6);
            console.log(condition);

           if(dice !== 1 || lastRoll !== 6) {
             lastRoll = dice;
             console.log('success');
           }
           else {
             lastRoll = 0;
             console.log('fail');
           }
        });
```

And type dice=1 and lastRoll=6 in the console before resuming, you'll see the "fail" message appear.